# Reporting on Total Events by Custom Dimension (Pageview Hit) - is it possible?

Tags: google-analytics, custom-dimensions

I am trying to report on a type of event aggregated sum, segmented by a custom dimension "Author."

I've created a custom dimension, "Author", that goes with the Pageview to GA, ergo now I can report on sessions by Author, bounce rate by Author, all page-level behavior metrics:

| Page | Author | Pageviews |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pages/page1 | Firstname Lastname | 23,025 |
| pages/page1 | John Smith | 21,051 |

I am using Scroll Events to track scroll depth, i.e. scroll down 10%, fire a hit. 25%, fire another hit, etc. non-interaction. So I should have an aggregate distribution of 10%, 25%, 50% etc. buckets of Scroll Events by page, and I've confirmed I am able to report on Total Events metric by Page as the dimension.

My goal is to report on scroll events by Author. I cannot get my head around why I cannot bucket Total Events by Author, as it returns 0 Total Events each time:

| Page | Author | Pageviews | Total Events |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pages/page1 | Firstname Lastname | 23,025 | 0 |
| pages/page1 | John Smith | 21,051 | 0 |